# Reemplazar letras al escribir Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

es posible hacer que cuando el usuario escriba dentro de un `"raw_input"` en vez de mostrar lo que escribe `(ej: "hola")` solo muestre un signo `(ej: "****")`, como si se tratara de una clave. ¿Es posible hacerlo con Py2.7? Si se requiere 3.7 y algun modulo no es problema. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')
```

Comment: @LucaMendez probablemente está ejecutando el código en el IDLE o en la consola embebida de algún IDE y no en la terminal/CMD del sistema. No es un error es una advertencia indicando que al no poder tomar el control de la  salida la operación es insegura y  puede que la contraseña se muestre. Por cierto la función de`getpass` no es sustituir los caracteres ingresados por stdin por asteriscos, sino proveer una forma segura de ingresar contraseñas, de hecho en linux (tty) no imprime asteriscos, no muestra nada directamente.